# Pause a loop, but still be able to see the text

Tags: java, textarea, sleep

I have a problem.
I draw something using a loop and I use Sleep to pause the execution. 
In the meantime, I want to be able to see what's in a textArea, which has a lot of lines and I have to scroll down to see them.But I can't.Using Sleep it's not possible.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: You will have to factor whatever your loop is doing out into another thread. It'll be difficult for people to answer here based just on this question. If it doesn't make sense to factor it out to another thread, it may be better to create a timer and do your loop duty each time the timer is called (set the timer to fire at the same interval as your sleep call... if you performed the loop more than once before sleeping, just perform the loop that many times during the timer invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use sleep on the event thread. I assume that yours is a Swing application (please tell us if this is correct or not), and if so, calling `Thread.sleep(...)` on the event thread will put your whole GUI asleep making it unresponsive.  Instead, if this is a Swing application, use a Swing Timer.

Tutorial: [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

**Edit 1**
Note: there are many recommendations here to use a SwingWorker, and these can be useful, but I would hold off using them unless the code that needs to be done between the time gaps is very CPU intensive and takes a bit of time to complete, such as reading in a medium to large file. If all you're doing is drawing a circle, then pausing, then drawing another circle, a SwingWorker is gross overkill and again a Swing Timer, which is much easier to implement, is the way to go.

As with all recommendations, the answers will depend on the specifics of your problem, and you may wish to tell us more.

Comment: +1 for the edit, certainly since in the comments he mentioned he only wants to do some painting (which should happen on the EDT) and then wait some time before the next paint

Comment: Thank you. you guys are great.I didn't expect to get so many responses.

Comment: @ada90: You're quite welcome. I think that you're seeing this number of responses because it's a fairly interesting topic, and it's a one of the hurdle type problems that when understood and mastered can improve your GUI coding considerably.

Answer (score 1):

You should never call `sleep` on the UI thread, since this will block all UI related operations (as you just discovered).

The typical use-case with a UI is to do the heavy work on a worker thread (like for example provided by the `SwingWorker` class) and update your UI when the work is done (or at certain intervals to display progress).

If you want to execute some code at certain intervals, you use the `Timer` (the Swing variant, not the `java.util` version), which will execute its code on the correct thread and leave the UI thread free between two executions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a Java beginner and your response was very useful. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to basically remember the state of the loop (where you'd got to etc) and stop adding. Let the user scroll around, and when you want to "unpause", resume the loop from where you'd got to.

Alternatively, perform the looping in a separate thread, using appropriate `SwingWorker` etc calls to marshal back to the UI thread to affect the UI, and then sleep in the other thread. That won't affect the UI. It's likely to get pretty fiddly though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have not posted any code snippet and have not explained clearly what does it mean that you cannot scroll down your text area.

But I can suppose that your UI is frozen because you are invoking `sleep()` in UI thread. Probably it is called from your overloaded `paint()` or `repaint()` method? If my guess is correct try to do your loop and sleep from separate thread. You can probably use `SwingWorker`.

To give you more concrete recommendations I need more information.

Comment: I have to paint something on a panel, let's say 6 circles, and for each one I have some information, in another panel which contains a textArea. When the loop it's paused I want to be able to click on the textArea from the other panel and scroll it down to the end of it.